# Copy array having only void* of it

Tags: c++, arrays

I have void* and I know that it is an array.

I have other array as a member of a structure. I know its type and length (it matches void* array).

I need to copy contents of void* array to other array in a structure.

This example describes my question:

```
// This function does not concern me - do not pay attention at memory managemt
void* getObject()
{
    uint32_t* oldArr = new uint32_t[2];
    oldArr[0] = 1;
    oldArr[1] = 2;

    void* obj = static_cast<void*>(oldArr);

    return obj;
};

struct ArrayStruct
{
    uint32_t dest[2];
};

int main()
{
    void* obj = getObject();
    ArrayStruct s;

    // What I need to do now is to assign values of obj to arrayStruct.dest
    // and I wonder what the best way to do it is?
}
```

I need to do it without warnings in C++11 without usage of any libraries except std.

I have such implementation but it makes a warning and I doubt that it is optimal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

// This function does not concern me - do not pay attention at memory managemt
void* getObject()
{
    uint32_t* oldArr = new uint32_t[2];
    oldArr[0] = 1;
    oldArr[1] = 2;

    void* obj = static_cast<void*>(oldArr);

    return obj;
};

struct ArrayStruct
{
    uint32_t dest[2];
};

bool GetArrayData(uint32_t arr[], void* data, uint32_t size)
{
    int length = size / sizeof(uint32_t);

    uint32_t (*array)[length] = (uint32_t (*)[length]) data;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr[i] = array[0][i];
    }

    return true;
};

int main()
{
    void* obj = getObject();
    ArrayStruct s;

    // What I need to do now is to assign values of obj to arrayStruct.dest
    // and I wonder what the best way to do it is?

    GetArrayData(s.dest, obj, sizeof(s.dest));

    cout << s.dest[0] << " " << s.dest[1];
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try memcpy?  Assuming your array is plain old blittable data?

Comment: Try to restructure/rearchitect/rework your code to *NOT* use `void*`. The type system is your *friend* - don't subvert it.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way (see comments for more information):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>

// This function does not concern me - do not pay attention at memory managemt
void* getObject()
{
    uint32_t* oldArr = new uint32_t[2];
    oldArr[0] = 1;
    oldArr[1] = 2;

    // no need for a cast
    return oldArr;
};

struct ArrayStruct
{
    uint32_t dest[2];
};

void copy_to(ArrayStruct& as, void const* type_erased_source)
{
    // std::extent gives us the number of elements in an array
    constexpr auto elements = std::extent<decltype(as.dest)>::value;

    // cast the void* to the correct pointer type
    auto source = reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t const*>(type_erased_source);

    // copy the objects to dest
    std::copy(source, source + elements, std::begin(as.dest));
}

int main()
{
    void* obj = getObject();
    ArrayStruct s;

    copy_to(s, obj);

    std::cout << s.dest[0] << " " << s.dest[1];
}
```

If you look at some example assembler on godbolt, you will see that the function `copy_to` is eventually compiled into one memory move.

https://godbolt.org/z/ALdq6e

```
copy_to(ArrayStruct&, void const*):
  mov rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
  mov QWORD PTR [rdi], rax
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

```
#include <cstring>

void GetArrayData(uint32_t arr[], void* data, uint32_t size)
{
  std::memcpy(arr, data, size * sizeof(uint32_t));
}
```

In case you manage to refactor the code and avoid the `void*`, [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) can be used:

```
void GetArrayData(uint32_t arr[], uint32_t* data, uint32_t size)
{
  std::copy(data, data+size, arr);
}
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that `memcpy` works only if the elements are trivially copyable (which the type used in the example is).